# Multiple X-axis values in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line graph which can drop down in a straight line. e.g. I have a point at (1, 100) then a point at (1,0). However, highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/) will only display information for one of the points. Is it possible to get it to show information on both points when I hover over each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for line type series is `findNearestPoint: 'x'` https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.findNearestPointBy .
If you change that to `findNearestPoint: 'xy'`, you'll get the behavior you want.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    findNearestPointBy:'xy',
    data: [
      [0, 29.9],
      [1, 50],
      [1, 71.5],
      [3, 106.4]
    ]
  }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vt1cep0L/2/